# how can i insert data from a html form into mysql database 2

Tags: php, mysql

**i want to insert student result that he calculate some equation and send it to his cell in users database

my problem is i cant send the result of some student to his own cell in the users table 
when i try to do it ,,its always (result) go to the first user that i logged in with ,, i think the issues with my SESSION 
can any 1 help please ???
my index.php code was**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Work Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="login.php?login=yes"  method="POST">
<table border=1>  
<tr> 
<td> username : <input type="text"  name="username"/></td>
<br />
<td>  password  :<input type="password"  name="password"/> </td>  
</tr>  
</table>

<input type="submit"  name="resultbtn"  value='login'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**and my login.php code is**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$login = $_GET['login'];
setcookie("username","$username",time()+15);
if($login=='yes') {
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("members");

$get = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' ");
$resultt = mysql_result($get,0);

if($resultt !=1){
  echo "error with login";
  }
else {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ";
  $myval = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "welcome back  " . $_COOKIE['username'];
echo"
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<html dir='rtl'>
<meta charset ='Windows-1256'>
</html>
<table>  
<tr> 
<th> </th>
</tr>";

if ($val = mysql_fetch_array($myval)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo " <td>" . "the question : calculate the triangle area if H = " . "</td>";
echo " <td> <input type='text'  value= $val[val1] disabled='disabled' size=5/> ". "</td>";
echo " <td>and L = <input type='text'  value= $val[val2]  disabled='disabled' size=5/> ". "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
     }
echo "</table>";
}
}
echo"<form action='result.php' method='POST'>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Hello student the result will be : <input type='text' name='add' ></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='send results'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
";
?>
```

**and the result.php (the page with my problems) code is**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$val3 = $_POST["add"];

//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("members");

//insert

$insert_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET results='$val3' WHERE username ='$_SESSION[username]' ");

$query = mysqli_query($insert_query) or die(mysqli_error());


//check whether the data insertion was successful

if(!$insert_query)

echo "<p>Sorry! Something went wrong.</p>";

else

echo "<p>Thanks! Your Results has been Sent.</p>";
```

?>

**my logout.php code is**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_destroy();
header ("location: index.php");
?>
```

**please HELP**

Comment: So, what's the problem? All I see is a code dump. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Limit your question to the  relevant code.

Comment: I don't read whole code but why you have mysql and mysqli functions mixed together?

Comment: @Facedown i have forget it ,, but even if i try mysql it dosn't works ... its always give result to the first user that i logged in with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is so bad written and uses mysql deprecated functions, anyway it doesn't work because of this:

```
$insert_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET results='$val3' WHERE username ='$_SESSION[username]' ");
```

You can't place an array value into a string that way. Try instead:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$insert_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET results='$val3' WHERE username ='$username' ");
```

Or:

```
$insert_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET results='$val3' WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Also, this row has no sense since $insert_query is the result of a mysql_query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($insert_query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: i did what u said and the same .. when i try to login with user (4) for example and when i press the send result button its gives the value to the user (2) that i first logged with > the code was 

    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $val3 = $_POST["add"];

//connect

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("members");

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $insert_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET results='$val3' WHERE username ='$username' ");
    echo "<p>Thanks! Your form has been processed.</p>";
    ?>'

Comment: If you do a echo $_SESSION['username'] what does it prints?

Comment: And why are you using both cookies and sessions?

Comment: setcookie("username","$username",time()+15); this cookie lasts only 15 seconds... almost useless

Comment: yes i know its last only 15 sec. i did that cuz i just want to see if the session will expire and i was hope that i can insert into another result cell

Comment: i will try to echo  $_SESSION['username'] and see what will print

Comment: i did what u say and its prints user that iam already logged in with ,,, but the same issue its give the value to first user that iam logged in with

Comment: the user that is prints is write or wrong? if it's wrong you have some problem with the login/logout...

Comment: its print the user that i was logged in ,, i mean its right ,